# Cannot figure out what's wrong with beautifulsoup4 in my python 3 script

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "urlgrabber.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   File "/Users/asdf/Desktop/Scraper/bs4/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry   File "/Users/asdf/Desktop/Scraper/bs4/builder/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from bs4.element import (   File "/Users/asdf/Desktop/Scraper/bs4/element.py", line 5, in <module>
    from bs4.dammit import EntitySubstitution   File "/Users/asdf/Desktop/Scraper/bs4/dammit.py", line 13, in <module>
    import logging   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from string import Template ImportError: cannot import name 'Template'
```

I have code that basically scrapes link off of a website. It was working fine till recently it just started returning this error on the command prompt. I am using python 3. I have downloaded bs4 and updated it along with python. I am still getting this error. Still new to Python/programming and am not sure how to fix this. I put the command prompt's messages up above. Code before was standard scraping code that worked fine but for some reason as of recently was not working. I can have 'from bs4 import BeautifulSoup' on a new .py file and it'll give me the same error:

```
File "bs4fml.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  File "/Users/asdf/Desktop/Scraper/bs4/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry
  File "/Users/asdf/Desktop/Scraper/bs4/builder/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from bs4.element import (
  File "/Users/asdf/Desktop/Scraper/bs4/element.py", line 5, in <module>
    from bs4.dammit import EntitySubstitution
  File "/Users/asdf/Desktop/Scraper/bs4/dammit.py", line 13, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from string import Template
```

Comment: Is there a string.py or string.pyc file in your working directory?

Comment: Still new to this but by working directory do you mean the folder the file I tried to run under? If so, yes there was a string.py in that folder but it was just trash code to test a snippet out. I deleted it and same error still comes up.

Comment: Yes, the working directory is the directory from where you are executing your code. You should delete both the string.py and string.pyc files. What's happening is Python is trying to import your string library instead of it's own.

Comment: omg it worked. something I spent 3 days messing with to no avail. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great! Glad to help! I'll add it as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched your error message and came up with this:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=142036

It looks like the problem is that Python is trying to `import from string` from a local source instead of its own string library because you have a similarly named `string.py` and/or `string.pyc` file in your working directory.

Try deleting both the string.py and string.pyc files and re-run your script.

Comment: Great! I added it as an answer so you could accept it as a working solution!