# Can requests be used to print all elements in the scroll at the top of a Google search?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, google-search

The goal is to print the text of all neighborhoods in the scroll at the top of a Google search when entering a term like "New York City neighborhoods"

Although there is no encoding issue when using requests as...

```
googleSearch = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=new+york+city+neighborhoods').content, "html.parser")
```

...it doesn’t return all of the response HTML that I was expecting (only a few items in the scroll exist, despite the Postman and Chrome response showing all of them) [1] , which is why the following method is being attempted (but has an encoding issue for me):

```
url = "https://www.google.com/search"

querystring = {"q":"New York City neighborhoods"}

headers = {
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': "1",
    'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36",
    'x-chrome-uma-enabled': "1",
    'x-client-data': "CIy2yQEIo7bJAQjEtskBCIuZygEI+pzKAQipncoB",
    'accept': "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    'accept-encoding': "gzip, deflate, sdch, br",
    'avail-dictionary': "MC9c6ZtH",
    'accept-language': "en-US,en;q=0.8",
    'cookie': "HSID=AQGYffYcWgUgwoIGG; SSID=AsyTtOTpG3P0TWe_e; APISID=DZOqFSNpfZmThOP6/A15eY85jEZTDT47_j; SAPISID=4jqCaE3zLEcO8GG4/ANI8HEy3etCmKfit2; SID=4AMk07dZM5wKaFcBAD7PgfLgMV1imGkqULwEdE9VI3lwoNRghaVTGT4ZT0mCGgzehY3mFg.; OGPC=5062210-7:765334528-2:699960320-1:961419264-9:; NID=97=bZNps3TAJFPAppe9EQbLyUDwXDbEFN57lT_capK2DQMWMVo7nEnYlPV-_g5OkOCERrN6MS5PxJXuVUOhjHeZGhCkS4FubcEapEzyuSQVS9rJM99rPzwE98ra47eP-ay0YTR-TawjFJ-0hAqT_j7SI7vQGVIU6yj4awM0hEt4ZXTd4k0RnH6kJPb0qVCc8AnQQLg4VZ0Kc1s83vJo6k7jFm-GCEoi; HSID=AQGYffYcWgUgwoIGG; SSID=AsyTtOTpG3P0TWe_e; APISID=DZOqFSNpfZmThOP6/A15eY85jEZTDT47_j; SAPISID=4jqCaE3zLEcO8GG4/ANI8HEy3etCmKfit2; SID=4AMk07dZM5wKaFcBAD7PgfLgMV1imGkqULwEdE9VI3lwoNRghaVTGT4ZT0mCGgzehY3mFg.; OGPC=5062210-7:765334528-2:699960320-1:961419264-9:; NID=97=bZNps3TAJFPAppe9EQbLyUDwXDbEFN57lT_capK2DQMWMVo7nEnYlPV-_g5OkOCERrN6MS5PxJXuVUOhjHeZGhCkS4FubcEapEzyuSQVS9rJM99rPzwE98ra47eP-ay0YTR-TawjFJ-0hAqT_j7SI7vQGVIU6yj4awM0hEt4ZXTd4k0RnH6kJPb0qVCc8AnQQLg4VZ0Kc1s83vJo6k7jFm-GCEoi; DV=Qg7Cq8EJDPcYvgxe_quK9y6d3FXJtAI",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'postman-token': "e6cec459-250e-1795-0e78-c450e5dfd56b"
    }
```

When attempting to retreive the response (which has a 200 status code):

```
googleSearch = BeautifulSoup(requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring).content, "html.parser")
```

`googleSearch.text` prints as:

No handlers could be found for logger "bs4.dammit"
��������[�#ٕ ֑�RK=��V��i$�YU��$���+Y�j2H&��L>"*��R*^$��gDefukz0�j���|�ax`���1��k�a��6`y=���X���X�þ��`ɬ.MK;�pgoĽ�{��{��D5�gǇ�������o}�?��[��듟���[ �ݷ��*����޾�9C�m�BFQ|�

…with much more of the weird characters

Can requests be used for a google search, or is another module necessary?

[1] expected HTML: The html shown in the response in the Postman app and Chrome contains div[class=“kltat”] elements (every item in the scroll at the top of the page (neighborhoods in this case) even if not shown yet on the scroll), whereas the other data contains HTML that only contains some of the scroll items and no div[class=“kltat”] elements

Comment: Yes I tried in Python 2.7.13. Which OS are you on? Could be related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38697915/cannot-figure-out-whats-wrong-with-beautifulsoup4-in-my-python-3-script)

Comment: running Python 2.7.10 on MacOS Sierra in PyCharm

Comment: Just to confirm, are you able to print all neighborhoods in the scroll (the text of div[class="kltat"] elements)

Comment: I tried `googleSearch.find_all('div', class_="kitat")` and `googleSearch.text.find('kitat')` but there doesn't seem to be any kitat divs. Are you sure they are not added by javascript after your browser has made the request? I'd try using an official API instead of scraping Google.

Comment: the i should be a lowercase L I believe

Comment: Oops, my bad. Still same result though.

Comment: Using your cookie seems like a bad idea as well. Not sure how that plays out behind the scenes.

Comment: It is against Google's [Webmaster Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/webmaster-guidelines) and [terms of service](https://policies.google.com/terms/archive/20020906?hl=en) to submit programmatic search queries.  Running this code against Google is likely to cause Google to show captcha for searches from your IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including this line is telling google's server's they can respond using [http-compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression):

```
'accept-encoding': "gzip, deflate, sdch, br"
```

My guess is that the compression used is `gzip`, although it is also allowing deflate, Brotli, and Google Shared Dictionary Compression.

You can remove the `accept-encoding` line from your headers; or import the gzip library and unzip the contents.

Comment: This was very incisive and solved the problem. `neighborhoods = [dv.text for dv in googleSearch.find_all('div', {'class':'kltat'})]` used with the method with the original encoding/compression issue works (containing all elements of the scroll)

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to send only `user-agent`, the rest of the headers is, as far as I know, overkill.

The weird characters (*binary*) come because you were using `.content` method which [returns binary data for non-text requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content) and `"accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch, br"` headers, you need to use `.text` method instead which [automatically decodes the content](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content) thus you don't receive the weird characters.

Code below scrapes (in this case, 33 elements out of ~40+), to get more results you need to use `selenium` or other browser automation and click on the right arrow button in order to load other elements and scrape them.

---

Code and example in the [online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-Google-Top-Carousel-Results-with-Python#bs4_result.py) that scrapes thumbnails as well:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml, re, json

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  'q': 'new york city neighborhoods',
  'gl': 'us',
}

def bs4_get_top_carousel():

  html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

  carousel_name = soup.select_one('.F0gfrd+ .z4P7Tc').text

  data = {f"{carousel_name}": []}

  all_script_tags = soup.select('script')

  # https://regex101.com/r/NYdrL5/1
  thumbnails = re.findall(r"<script nonce=\".*?\">\(\w+\(\)\{\w+\s?\w+='(.*?)';\w+\s?\w+=\['\w+'\];\w+\(\w+,\w+\);\}\)\(\);<\/script>", str(all_script_tags))

  for result, thumbnail in zip(soup.select('.ct5Ked'), thumbnails):
    title = result["aria-label"]
    link = f"https://www.google.com{result['href']}"
    try:
      extensions = result.select_one(".cp7THd .FozYP").text
    except: extensions = None
    
    decoded_thumbnail = bytes(thumbnail, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
    # print(f'{title}\n{link}\n{extensions}\n{decoded_thumbnail}\n')

    data[carousel_name].append({
      'title': title,
      'link': link,
      'extensions': [extensions],
      'thumbnail': decoded_thumbnail
    })
  
  print(json.dumps(data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))

---------------------
'''
]
 ...
   {
      "title": "Lower East Side",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/search?gl=us&q=Lower+East+Side&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgFuLUz9U3MIo3sjBTAjMNKy2NzbUUspOt9HPykxNLMvPz9AtyEpNTrfJSM9MzkvKLMvLzU4ofMfpxC7z8cU9YynXSmpPXGO25CGoREudic80rySypFOKV4uZCWGzFpMHEs4iV3ye_PLVIwTWxuEQhODMldQIbIwAs7VbHoAAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwimh-H-q93zAhXCZc0KHXj3DAYQ-BZ6BQgBEI4B",
      "extensions": [
        null
      ],
      "thumbnail": "data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
    }
  ...
]
'''
```

If you need more info about this topic, I wrote a dedicated blog post about [how to scrape Google Carousel results](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/scrape-google-carousel-results-with-python-47ba).

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Knowledge Graph API](https://serpapi.com/knowledge-graph) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you don't have to deal with the extraction process and figuring out what `CSS` selector to use or how to deal with other different things, instead you pretty much only need to iterate over structured JSON and get the data you want.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os, json

def serpapi_get_top_carousel():
    params = {
      "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
      "engine": "google",
      "q": "new york city neighborhoods",
      "hl": "en"
    }

    search = GoogleSearch(params)
    results = search.get_dict()

    for result in results['knowledge_graph']['neighborhoods']:
        print(json.dumps(result, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))


---------------
'''
"neighborhoods": [
  {
  "name":"Harlem",
  "link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=Harlem&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgFuLUz9U3MIo3sjBT4gAx0yxNSrQUspOt9HPykxNLMvPz9AtyEpNTrfJSM9MzkvKLMvLzU4ofMfpxC7z8cU9YynXSmpPXGO25CGoREudic80rySypFOKV4uZC2GvFpMHEs4iVzSOxKCc1dwIbIwBbfLXHlgAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiipvO2q93zAhUylGoFHcyFA4wQ-BZ6BAgBEDQ",
  "image": "https://serpapi.com/searches/61725341e4a23d51edb9dabf/images/d59e4f2f273f964cdd7164417183fc3f42a0f8724e78a4815f5e934903209df6acfc73bbca024b9a.jpeg"
  }
...
]
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.